# Merge two SQL queries on two columns

Tags: sql

I have two queries. I want to merge and one table and two columns.

```
SELECT COUNT(IsApproved) as CountNotApproved
FROM Erp_OrderReceipt 
WHERE IsApproved = 0
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(IsApproved) as CountApproved
FROM Erp_OrderReceipt 
WHERE IsApproved = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
SELECT COUNT(case when IsApproved = 0 then 0 end) as CountNotApproved, 
       COUNT(case when IsApproved = 1 then 1 end) as CountApproved
FROM Erp_OrderReceipt;
```

This works because aggregate functions ignore `NULL` values. The result of the `CASE` is `NULL` for all rows that do not match the condition.

If your DBMS supports this you can also use the ANSI SQL `filter` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (where IsApproved = 0) as CountNotApproved, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (where IsApproved = 1) as CountApproved
FROM Erp_OrderReceipt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Union and group for that

```
 SELECT SUM(CountApproved) CountApproved, 
        SUM(CountNotApproved) CountNotApproved
 FROM
 (
    SELECT 
        0 as CountApproved,
        COUNT(IsApproved) as CountNotApproved
    FROM Erp_OrderReceipt where IsApproved=0 
    UNION
    SELECT 
        COUNT(IsApproved) as CountApproved,
        0 as CountNotApproved
    FROM Erp_OrderReceipt where IsApproved=1
 ) u
```